# Benefit of Add Image By URL in wordpress?

Tags: seo, page-speed

In wordpress we can add image by three method. 1.Upload, 2.Media Lib. and 3.Insert image url. my question is, what is benefit of SEO when you choose 3 option(Insert image url). because i use 1st option(upload) on the one of my blogs to increase it's page speed.

Answer (score 2):

All images are going to be a URL in a webpage no matter how you load them in Wordpress. The html will be something like `<img src="example.com/myimage.jpg" alt="my images">`  The only difference in the 3 options is the location Wordpress uses to write the `<img>` tag.  As a result, I doubt that there's any difference to SEO unless the image URL is to another website, in which case you a might pass a miniscule amount of link juice.

The three choices will either be (1)a new file you add to your image library, (2) an existing file you have in your image library or (3) a URL to where the file is already hosted on a website.

Comment: suppose we use option 3rd, so increse the speed of web page?

Comment: Doesn't WordPress create both a real URL and an HTML page containing nothing but the image for anything uploaded to the Media Lib?    I seem to recall Yoast trying to fix that issue: https://yoast.com/help/redirect-image-attachment-urls/

Comment: @RahulWaware, if you want to increase the page speed for images, consider using a Content Delivery Network (CDN).  These services will host your images, CSS and Javascript on high capacity servers, and can increase your page speed.  Option 3 might speed up your web server if you hosted your images externally but wouild also mean an additional client HTTP connection for the web browser.  From an HTTP process, your browser would have to resolve and initiate an additional HTTP connection to the remote URL.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller thanks for pointing that out.  I had wondered why all of my WP images were getting backlinks.  That explains it.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an image by URL allows the image to be stored elsewhere.  This has multiple potential benefits in some niche circumstances including -

- Storing images on a CDN to distribute them to provide faster loading.
- Interfacing with other systems (eg calling the image can be used for tracking purposes on a custom built/separate system.   You could also, for example, have different images provided depending on location of visitor or other criteria.
- You could keep the images outside the purview of Wordpress.  Wordpress tends to keep images in wp-content/uploads/year/month/image.file - sometimes this is not logical for some images.

For the most part, if you are just using Wordpress (or if you need to ask the question), you don't need to worry about it.